# Scrollbar in TKinter class is not interactive

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I have a lot of Labels in a frame in TKinter. I would like a scrollbar to see all the labels that appear out of the screen. What I have currently tried does not work. Here is a MWE:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

fontcolor = '#3a346f'

class SecurityProperties(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        # Set up scroll bar
        self.main_frame = Frame(self)
        self.main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.my_canvas = Canvas(self.main_frame)
        self.my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.my_scrollbar=ttk.Scrollbar(self.main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.my_canvas.yview)
        self.my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.my_scrollbar.set)
        self.my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.my_canvas.bbox("all")))

        self.second_frame = Frame(self.my_canvas)
        self.my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.second_frame, anchor= "nw")

        helv15 = font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=15,weight="bold")

        self.UpperTextBox = Label(self.second_frame, bg = "white", relief = GROOVE, text = "Information", font = helv15, fg = fontcolor)
        self.UpperTextBox.place(relheight = 0.15, relwidth = 0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)
```

A scrollbar appears but is not interactive. Note the MWE has only one button, but the scrollbar does not work even when there are more labels that disappear off-screen. How can I make the scrollbar work?

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` on `self.second_frame` instead of `self.my_canvas`. Note that the vertical scrollbar will be activated only when the height of `self.second_frame` is greater than the height of `self.my_canvas`.

Comment: @acw1668, I still get an empty screen when I try this.

Comment: It is because the size of `self.second_frame` is 1x1 as you put the text using `.place()` which does not affect its parent size.  Try setting `width` and `height` options (for example 300 and 1000 correspondingly) when creating `self.second_frame`.

Comment: @acw1668, that seemed to work. Is it possible to define the width and height to match that of `self.my_canvas`?

Comment: Setting the width and height same as the canvas will make the scrollbar not activated.

Comment: @acw1668, sure, but defining `width` and `height` for `self.second_frame` changes the dimensions of each of the Labels. Was wondering if there is a workaround to keep the dimensions unchanged?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249226/discussion-between-sid-and-acw1668).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you update the `scrollregion` whenever you add or remove data to the canvas, or when the data on the canvas changes size. Your code only updates it when the canvas itself is resized.

Comment: OK, how is this achieved?

Comment: I.e. are you able to add some lines of code that can be tried out